# Partial derivatives and functions equal to 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, differential-geometry, graphing-functions, partial-derivative

If I have the function (family of curves) 
$$F(x,y,p)=(px)^2+p=0$$ 
I am under the impression that
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y,p)}{\partial p}=2px^2+1$$
Is not always equal to $0$.

Please could you explain this to me?

Comment: $F(x,y,p)$ is not always equal to zero either. Let $p,x=1$ and see if it is equal then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct: it's not always equal to zero. Nor should you expect it to be.

Let's look at a simpler example, in one variable, $x$. Let
$$f(x)=x$$
The equation $f(x)=x=0$ represents a set of solutions: in this case, the set $\{0\}$. Differentiating, we get $f'(x)=1=0$, which is clearly absurd, and should indicate that you can't do such a thing and expect it to make sense.

There are two possible different definitions of "equals" here. If $f$ and $g$ are identically the same function, then indeed $f'=g'$ for all inputs $x$ -- we could say $f'\equiv g'$. However, $f(x)=g(x)$ is commonly used to refer to the set of values $x$ for which both $f$ and $g$ return the same value -- for example, if $f(x)=x$ as above and $g(x)=x^2$, these functions take the same value for $x=0$ and $x=1$ while not being identical.

Comment: But if f(x)=g(x) does f '(x) not = g'(x) what is the difference??

Comment: added another paragraph: does this help?

Comment: so in we should actually write f(x) ≡ g(x) (i.e. true for all x) but f(x)=0 then f '(x) ≡ g'(x) but f'(x) does not equal 0???

Comment: Indeed, $f\equiv g$ would unambiguously refer to the first case; without it, it's usual to assume the latter.

Comment: Thanks this has really helped me (i have been confused about it for ages)